# Flash builder 4.6 camera app mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder, android-camera

Hi all I am working on a mobile camera app in Flash builder 4.6. 
My problem is that I can get the camera working with a webcam but not a mobile camera where it is to be deployed. I am using AIR trying to stream.
This is how I call my button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Capture"> 
        <!-- Button event script -->
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                {
                    //Bring in the actionscript
                    import views.CoolVideo;
                    //The button handler
                    private function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                    {
                        //Calling the actionScript function
                        new CoolVideo();
                    }
                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>
        <!-- Basic structure of the app page -->
        <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">  
            <!-- Label on the screen -->
            <s:Label text="Capture page(current)"/>
            <!-- Button to change between screens -->
            <s:Button label="Capture" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" styleName="next"/>  
            <s:Button label="Back" click="navigator.pushView(app3HomeView)" styleName="next"/>  
            <!--<s:Image id="img" height="649" y="124" width="460" x="10"/> -->
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:View>
```

Here I call my action-script with a button handler `button1_clickHandler` which goes to the actionscript:

```
package views
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.CameraUI;
    import flash.media.H264Level;
    import flash.media.H264Profile;
    import flash.media.H264VideoStreamSettings;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class CoolVideo extends Sprite
    {
        //All the Stuff we need
        private var metaText:TextField = new TextField();
        private var vid_outDescription:TextField = new TextField();
        private var vid_inDescription:TextField = new TextField();
        private var metaTextTitle:TextField = new TextField();

        //the connection will be used to link to server
        private var nc:NetConnection;

        //net stream is the data flow
        private var ns_out:NetStream;

        //the camera, get camera looks for an available camera returns null if not one available
        private var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();

        //this will be the video streamed to the server
        private var vid_out:Video;



        //Class constructor
        public function CoolVideo()
        {   
            //Call initConnection()
            initConnection();
        }

        //Called from class constructor, this function establishes a new NetConnection and listens for its status
        private function initConnection():void
        {
            //instantiate netConnection
            nc = new NetConnection();

            //The on status event is where all the streaming will go on
            nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);

            //make net Connection to the server
            nc.connect("rtmp://192.168.200.233/livepkgr/_definst_/");

            //Step 7: Tell the NetConnection where the server should invoke callback methods
            nc.client=this;

            //Instantiate the vid_out variable
            vid_out = new Video();
        }

        //It's a best practice to always check for a successful NetConnection
        protected function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            //Step 8: Trace the value of event.info.code
            trace(event.info.code);

            /*Step 9: Check for a successful NetConnection, and if successful
            call publishCamera()*/
            if(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
            { 
                publishCamera(); 
            }
        }

        //The encoding settings are set on the publishing stream
        protected function publishCamera():void
        {
            //Step 12: Instantiate the ns_out NetStream
            ns_out = new NetStream(nc);

            //Step 13: Attach the camera to the outgoing NetStream
            ns_out.attachCamera(cam);

            //Step 14: Define a local variable named h264Settings of type H264VideoStreamSettings
            var h264Settings:H264VideoStreamSettings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();

            //Step 15: Set encoding profile and level on h264Settings
            h264Settings.setProfileLevel( H264Profile.BASELINE, H264Level.LEVEL_3_1 )

            //Step 16: Set the bitrate and quality settings on the Camera object
            cam.setQuality( 90000, 90 );

            //Step 17: Set the video's height, width, fps, and whether it should maintain its capture size
            cam.setMode( 320, 240, 30, true );

            //Step 18: Set the keyframe interval
            cam.setKeyFrameInterval( 15 );

            //Step 19: Set the outgoing video's compression settings based on h264Settings
            ns_out.videoStreamSettings = h264Settings;

            //Step 20: Publish the outgoing stream
            ns_out.publish( "livestream?adbe-live-event=liveevent" );

        }

        //Step 11: Un-comment this necessary callback function that checks bandwith (remains empty in this case)
        public function onBWDone():void
        {
        }
    }

}
```

If someone could shed a bit of light as to why it does not run on the mobile camera but does on the webcam that would be great or even to point me in the right direction

Comment: What I do find strange is that your sample is actually running in desktop mode with a webcam, since I see no place where your **CoolVideo** sprite is being added to stage or display view.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu sorry now how would I go about implementing that like would i try use the child to add a cam??

Comment: you are instantiating the new CoolVideo(); but do not add it to view. how about this.addElement(new CollVideo()); I have the feeling you are not using the same sample as in your desktop air app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check all your permissions, as if it is working in the emulated environment that's pretty much what it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

To access the device camera in Android, you need to request it in the `<uses-permision>` section of your [`appManifest.xml`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129d39606f2-8000) file under the `<android>` root

EG:

```
    <android>
        <colorDepth>16bit</colorDepth>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
            </manifest>

        ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
```

Comment: I checked the permissions they are allowed still nothing @CyanAngel

Comment: hmm, ok. Have you tried outputting the `Camera` to a UI element like a `VideoDisplay` to check your actually getting output.